# Tuple structure equivalent in Matlab

Tags: matlab, haskell, tuples

In Haskell, there is a structure called 'tuples' which allows two elements to be paired together (Ie: (1,2), ('A', 'B') etc)

I was wondering if there was something similar in Matlab so that I could match elements and then query matlab in a way similar to "If element X is matched to Y then.. else.."

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the type of data you are handling, you may want to use `structs` or `cells`.

Comment: sort of like a dictionary/map?

Answer (score 3):

The closet thing I know of in MATLAB is to use a `map` object. They are pretty easy to use. You can create one as follows

```
someMap = containers.Map();
```

Adding a new key is pretty easy as well

```
someMap('someKey') = 'someValue';
```

The key needs to be a string by default, but this can be edited. You can also check if the key exists already by calling

```
someMap.isKey('someKey')
```

And values are accessed by just calling

```
someMap('someKey')
```

This should mimic the behavior that you are looking for. You can always read more by looking at the documentation. [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html)

Answer (score 2):

A simple [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) may be able to do the trick for you:

```
C = {1, 2; 'A' 'B'}
```

You can now easily perform tests on it, for example:

```
strcmp(C, 'A')
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it does not really allow for a single result match. The comparison will return a full vector of 1 and 0 that will require some extra processing.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Its not hard to compare your value to a single element, for example `C{1,:}==2`. Or finding an index number: `[C{1,2}]==2`.

Comment: I know, I never said it was. I was just saying that strcmp will return a vector. You most certainly can, it will just like I said take a little more processing. The advantage of a map as I suggested is that it is constant time access and does not really required that extra processing