# What is the MATLAB equivalent of a named tuple in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, tuples, namedtuple

A `namedtuple` assigns names, as well as a numerical index, to each member, unlike the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378121/tuple-structure-equivalent-in-matlab).

For example, what would be the MATLAB equivalent of the following in Python:

`myRow = namedtuple("myRow",["datetime","B","C","D","E"])`

Comment: hmmm, a tuple suggests it can vary in length, i.e. {A -> ["datetime","B","C"],B-> ["datetime","D"]} I assume? If it is a fixed Dataframe, then matlab's equivalent is a Table.

Comment: There's no equivalent type in MATLAB.  Creating a named tuple is similar to creating a lightweight objects with different instance variables but they are **immutable**.  The closest thing you can get is to create a custom MATLAB object and ensuring that you can't change the state of the object once you create it.

Comment: @GameOfThrows It is fixed. Would you be able to please expand upon applying a table structure to represent the named tuple above? One that would allow myRow to map values? I plan to, in python, ```row = myRow(datetime=dt, B=value1, C=value2, D=value3, E=value4)```.  Will add and edit above for clarification as well.

Comment: @rayryeng will this avoid the same type of bugs with concurrent multi-threaded code that tuples help avoid? Are you referring to ```SetAccess = immutable```? Would it be possible to please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
py.tuple({'my Row',{19,'Biology'}})
```

you can check the following page 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/list-tuple-and-dictionary-types.html